# Excel Crashing When Running This Code? (Transfer of Data from Excel To Word)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a user entry form in excel which users fill out and then data is inputted into a database. Sheet name "Database"

I then have written a piece of code to transfer data from a database to a template i have on word through the use of bookmarks.

Basically, i want the user to enter a works order number (as it is unique) into cell "D26" and then it will take this row of data from the excel database and transfer it to word.

However running this code, crashes excel. It goes not responding and doesn't come back until it is closed and then reopened

```
Dim wd As Object 'Word Application
Dim wdDOC As Object 'word document
Dim iRow As Long 'Variable to hold the starting row and loop through all records in database
Dim PercentageScore As Variant 'Variable to hold percentage score
Dim sh As Worksheet 'worksheet variable to refer  to where database is stored
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim WorksOrder As String


'Start word as new document

Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Get user entered WorksOrder Number

WorksOrder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("D26").Value  'Get user entered WorksOrder Number

'Set worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

iRow = 2 'row in which data starts from in database

Do While sh.Range("A" & iRow).Value <> "" 'loop through until no data is found (last row of database)
 
If WorksOrder = sh.Range("D" & iRow).Value Then

'opening word template

Set wdDOC = wd.Documents.Add("T:\mageeg\TEST DATA  INSPECTION SCHEDULE Issue 3.docx")

wd.Visible = False

'code to insert values from database to bookmarks in word

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="PartNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("C" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Serial"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("E" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ModelNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("B" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="WorksOrderNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("D" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="MaterialNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("F" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="SerialNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("E" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ModelNo2"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("B" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Type"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("H" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Size"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("I" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="WKPRESS"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("J" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="SerialNumber"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("G" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="CertDate"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("K" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="BatchNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("L" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="JobNo"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=sh.Range("M" & iRow).Value

wd.Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="DateOfManufacture"
wd.Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(sh.Range("N" & iRow).Value, "mmm-yy")


'code to delete the existing bookmarks from wordfile

On Error Resume Next

wdDOC.Bookmarks("PartNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("SerialNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("ModelNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("WorksOrderNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("MaterialNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("Serial").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("ModelNo2").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("Type").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("Size").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("WKPRESS").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("SerialNumber").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("CertDate").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("BatchNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("JobNo").Delete
wdDOC.Bookmarks("DateOfManufacture").Delete

'save file with new name

wdDOC.SaveAs2 (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sh.Range("D" & iRow).Value & ".docx")

'Print document


'close the word file

wdDOC.Close

'release memory of word doc

Set wdDOC = Nothing

iRow = iRow + 1

Exit Do

End If

Loop

wd.Quit 'close MS Word

Set wd = Nothing 'Release memory allocated to WD

MsgBox ("Inspection Test Sheet Created")

End Sub
```

However if i take out these 2 lines of code, it runs fine.

```
WorksOrder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("D26").Value  'Get user entered WorksOrder Number
If WorksOrder = sh.Range("D" & iRow).Value Then
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't do what i want, it takes all the rows from the database and transfers them to word.

I would like it to take just the row includes the WorksOrder number entered by the user in cell D26

Any ideas what was wrong with my code/how to fix it?

****NOTE!!** I have found more info, it is only crashing if the WorksOrder number written in Cell "D26" is not in the first row of the database. If the WorksOrder number written in row 1 is written, it works**

[First Posted on MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-not-responding-when-running-this-piece-of-code-what-am-i-missing.1174139/)

Comment: What do you mean with *crashes Excel*? What exactly happens? Do you get any error message? Or is Excel completley closed?

Comment: Hi @FunThomas sorry i should have been more clear. Excel goes not responding and hangs. It doesn't seem to come back even after 5 minutes. Only way to get it back is to close Excel and then reopen it

Comment: A shot in the dark... Rather 2 shots :P **1.** You are using latebinding it seems? If that is correct then Excel will not uderstand what the word constants are... `wdGoToBookmark` Declare `Private Const wdGoToBookmark As Integer = -1` at the top **2.** Add `DoEvents` after `wdDOC.SaveAs2....`

Comment: Also add `On Error GoTo 0` after `wdDOC.Bookmarks("DateOfManufacture").Delete`

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the suggestions, however they sadly have made no difference! I'm thinking it must be an issue with the second piece of code from the question as without these lines it works. But can't seem to find the issue

Comment: When using WorksOrder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("D26").Value  'Get user entered WorksOrder Number
If WorksOrder = sh.Range("D" & iRow).Value Then, at the end of the code before the Loop i have to put Exit Do End If, could the problem lay somewhere here? as again without these 2 lines and the Exit do/End If it works alright.

Comment: *NOTE* i have found more info, it is only crashing if the WorksOrder number written in Cell "D26" is not in the first row of the database. If the WorksOrder number written in row1 is referenced, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code only incremented iRow if the value is found. Otherwise it would check the same row over and over again.

I had to move iRow = iRow + 1 to after the end if